# Postman "unexpected-token error" on text-response

Tags: spring-boot, postman

My Spring-Controller has an endpoint configuration like this:

```
    @ApiOperation(value = "Bla",response = String.class, responseContainer = "")
    @ApiResponses(value = { /* some @ApiResponse error codes */ })
    @SomeAspectAnnotation
    @RequestTrace
    @RequestMapping(
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            value = "/{name}",
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    public ResponseEntity<String> getBenutzereinstellungenByName(
        @PathVariable() String name,
        @ApiParam(name = "Authorization", value = "JWT", required = true) @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String jwt,
        @ApiParam(name = "SomeParam", value = "Some Header Param") @RequestHeader(value = "Some-Param", required = false) String someParam
    ) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(name, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

when I call the url with a number at the end, I get `1` as the response in Postman. When I call it with "test", the server returns `Unexpected 't'`. Why? The PathVariable has a type String and there is no Regex-limitation in RequestMapping

> EDIT: changing `PathVariable()` to `@PathVariable(value = "name", name = "name", required = true)` did not help with the issue
>
> EDIT2: I changed the title of the question. It can be closed. The problem is that when postman expects an application/json-response it will take not take `"no"` for an answer, but `1` it will.

Comment: can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: Nevermind. It was a postman issue. It expected response of type JSON and got plaintext. Don't know why a numeric response works though